# ¿Por qué un shell funciona con un fork?

Tags: shell

¿Por qué un shell funciona así cuando ejecutamos un comando?

1. Se crea un `fork`
2. El proceso padre llama a `wait` y espera.
3. El proceso hijo llama a `exec` para ejecutar el programa deseado
4. El programa se ejecuta
5. El programa finaliza
6. El proceso padre se despierta

¿Por qué se crea un fork?. ¿Por qué el proceso padre no puede hacer todo por sí mismo?

Comment: yo he realizado algunos cambios gramaticales para que se entienda mejor, pero no tengo conocimientos profundos sobre lo que se pregunta, y se ve claramente que el usuario no domina el español. No es mejor intentar ajustar la pregunta antes de ir a cerrarla como si esto fuera una carrera, ademas de que ahora cuenta con una respuesta, que a poco que se conozca el tema se puede reformular la pregunta sin que pierda la esencia de la pregunta original. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Lo que realmente hace `execve`, es sustituir al proceso actual, de forma que éste deja de existir. Si llamas a `execve` desde el proceso padre, el proceso padre es sustituido por el programa invocado (suponiendo que no haya habido error), y cuando éste termine, ya no habrá proceso padre. Por tanto, si no quieres perder el proceso padre, hay que crear explícitamente un proceso hijo que después sea sustituido por otro mediante `execve`.

Por motivos históricos, en Unix crear un proceso hijo, y cargar un proceso desde un fichero ejecutable son dos pasos distintos (`fork` y `execve`). Esto tiene sus ventajas e inconvenientes, y tradicionalmente parecen haber sido más importantes las ventajas.

Ventajas:

- Añadir `fork` originalmente fue fácil . Originalmente sólo había dos procesos, uno por cada terminal que tenía el sistema original, la shell cargaba el proceso a ejecutar, y cuando el proceso terminaba se recargaba la shell. Pasar de este sistema a uno con múltiples procesos por terminal, requería añadir la funcionalidad de `fork` (crear un proceso hijo), pero no la de `execve` (cargar la memoria de un proceso desde un ejecutable), que ya se hacía a mano en la shell.
- Duplicar un proceso es muy eficiente, no hay que volver a cargarlo. Ésto permite un modo de multitarea similar a lo que se hace con múltiples hilos en otros sistemas. Como ejemplo, un servidor web puede constar de varios procesos idénticos, cada uno sirviendo a uno o más clientes.
- Se pueden hacer muchas preparaciones en el proceso hijo antes de cargar el programa a invocar.

Inconvenientes:

- Para el caso en el que simplemente se quiera invocar un programa distinto, llamar a `fork` y a `execve` puede parecer complicado. Históricamente no se ha considerado un problema, y es fácil crear una interfaz más sencilla a partir de `fork` y `execve`. Como ejemplo véase `system`, que internamente suele utilizar `fork` y `execve`.
- Para ese mismo caso, crear una copia de la memoria del proceso para luego descartarla puede parecer ineficiente. En los sistemas con memoria virtual surgió una optimización conocida como copia-en-escritura (COW, *copy-on-write*), por la cual sólo se copia la tabla de páginas, se marcan las páginas como de sólo lectura, y sólo se copia la memoria cuando se intenta escribir en esa memoria, es decir cuando la memoria empieza a ser diferente en padre e hijo.
- Duplicar la tabla de páginas para luego descartarla puede ser ineficiente en casos extremos (por ejemplo, ejecutar programas de unos pocos Kb desde un proceso que ocupe varios Gb), y el sistema operativo puede denegar el `fork` pensando que no habrá memoria suficiente. Hay diversas formas de solucionar ésto, desde lanzar los programas desde un pequeño proceso externo que se comunica con el programa principal mediante un socket o pipe, o utilizar `vfork/exec` o `posix_spawn` en lugar de `fork/exec`.

POSIX incluye una función que carga un programa en un nuevo proceso hijo en un solo paso, `posix_spawn`. Esta función está pensada sobre todo para ser usada en sistemas sin MMU, en los que `fork()` típicamente no existe, o es ineficiente. También se usa para lanzar programas pequeños desde procesos grandes.

Answer (score 0):

Principalmente por diseño, nada le impide al proceso padre executar `exec` por si mismo. Una de las razones es que existe algo que se llama process group que son varios procesos que se ejecutan al mismo tiempo y estan relaciodos en un `job`, por ejemplo cuando ejecutas un pipe `ls | grep boot`, el si interrumpes al proceso lider del grupo o le envias alguna otra señal por ejemplo `kill -9` acabarias con todos los proceson en el grupo incluido el shell mismo.